# is there a function to invoke python script from webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, raspberry-pi

I am very new to html and webpages(being an embedded engineer). I have got a task to automate few processes which requires a python script to be executed on Raspberry pi when we click a button on webpage.

What i want is a process where the python code can be executed directly on the pi when we click a button on the webpage. I have tried javascript, bryhton and pretty much everything that i could

Here is the html page that i designed.What this piece of code does is it reads the contents of python script rather than executing it on the board.

Please guys suggest me a method to do it. Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1><b>Remote Diagnostic Method</b></h1>
    <button id="greet-button"  onclick="RunPython()">Say Hello</button>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script >
          function RunPython()
        {
             $.ajax({
              url: "add.py",
            }).done(function(response) {
             alert(response);;
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

this looks like a job for [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/). it's a very lightweight web framework which is written in python, just follow the docs and you'll be able to set up what you want in no time as well as easily add functionality to whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: Another option is Django

Comment: Could also use fastapi

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jupyter notebook`, `Jupter Lab` to run server and run code from there.

install requirements
`pip install jupyter notebook`

then
`jupyter notebook`
you will be opened a web interface you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `. ajax()` function in the jQuery library. This will allow you to call your Python script as long as the script is in the publicly accessible html directory .

Comment: i tried .ajax() but it returns the content of the script rather than executing the script